# If radio streaming's connection is bad, What have to do next?

Tags: iphone, connection, audio-streaming, itunes, internet-radio

I made Radio Streaming Iphone App.
And submit to itunes app stroe.
But they rejected my app.
This is the reason.

```
2.2: Apps that exhibit bugs will be rejected
When the user taps on a radio, an alert is displayed stating the connection is lost   
and no further action can be produced.
```

Yes, If the connection failed, I let the connection bad message appear to screen.
But they demand that there should be further action.
Do you think What further action is needed?
Did you use Wunder Radio or Tunein Radio?  These app did same action if the connection failed.
Only shows connection error messase.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet here is to produce better user experience when connection is lost, has failed or was interrupted. I mean you should implement a mechanism visible to user that tries to reestablish connection with your streaming server based on network condition changes.

Also it would be good if you allow your users to trigger that action from the alert view you mentioned, e.g. "Connection is lost. Would you like to retry" + no/yes.

A good place to start with is adding [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Classes_Reachability_m.html) to your project (Apple has demo code which uses it).

Comment: Hi, I submitted the new version which have reachabillity, But I received the same message. What should I do?